# Find the order O of a function and ω(n), ο(n) and Θ(n)

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, functions, algorithms

I want to find if the function $c^{nlogn}, c>1$ is $O((nlogn)^{logn})$ or  $\Omega ((nlogn)^{logn})$
Im trying to analyze $c^{nlogn}$ to find the order but i cant.

I also want to find if the function $\sqrt{\sqrt[logn]{n^2}}$ is ω(n), ο(n),Θ(n)

Comment: My favorite lemma for these situations (let's say all functions tend to infinity): if $\log f(n) = o(\log g(n))$ then $f(n) = o(g(n))$. Can you prove it? (And see why it would be a false statement if $o$ were replaced by $O$?) Can you use it to resolve these functions?

Comment: Also note that $\sqrt[\log n]{n^2} = e^2$, exactly.... (or $10^2$ if your $\log$ means $\log$ base $10$)

Comment: Is it true to try to compute the lim f(x)/g(x) and if the limit is 0 then is o(n), if lim is oo then is ω(n) etc??